# Diskpart cannot see volumes

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, diskpart

I have an internal disk that is connected to my laptop via USB using a docking station. I am sure the hard disk contains volumes and the volumes are not corrupt. However, Windows 10 cannot read my hard disk properly. Here is some information from diskpart:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    No Media           0 B      0 B
  Disk 2    No Media           0 B      0 B
  Disk 3    Online         5589 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 3

Disk 3 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary             15 TB   4096 B

DISKPART> detail disk

SABRENT  SCSI Disk Device
Disk ID: 6AFB5B59
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

There are no volumes.
```

Note that the size of the disk is `5589 GB` when listing the disks (which is correct), but later it reads it as a `15 TB` partition. Any thoughts on how I can fix the issue and access data?

Comment: If it's connected *outside* the laptop, it's external, not internal. Also, try anbother tools, e.g. free DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/ . If ll tools state there are no volumes, then the partition table is gone. See https://superuser.com/questions/802202/if-diskpart-says-that-a-disk-has-no-volumes-is-the-disk-empty-of-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If Diskpart says that a disk has no volumes, is the disk empty of data?](https://superuser.com/questions/802202/if-diskpart-says-that-a-disk-has-no-volumes-is-the-disk-empty-of-data)

Comment: I've used that program, it did recover partitions but cannot open any of them. Windows says they need to be formatted before they can be explored.

Comment: It seems the data, or at least the old disk operating system, is gone. If you do not have a disk image (there are numerous free tools to make them, such as Macrium Reflect), your data is inaccessible. If there is something vital you **must** get back, there are disk recovery services that are quite expensive, but even those professional services cannot always recover data.